# Remove consecutive values in two dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array below:

```
$array = array(
  '90' => array (
     '11:00' => array(
     '    dept' => 297
      ),
     '11:01' => array(
         'dept' => 297
      ),
     '11:02' => array(
     '    dept' => 884
      ),
     '11:03' => array(
         'dept' => 297
      ),
   ),
  '91' => array (
     '11:00' => array(
       'dept' => 297
      ),
     '11:01' => array(
       'dept' => 297
      ),
   )
);
```

The 90 and 91 are userid. Now inside the 90 and 91 key I want to remove the consecutive value, for example dept 297 it should return only once.
The output I want is:

```
$array = array(
  '90' => array (
     '11:00' => array(
        'dept' => 297
       ),
      '11:02' => array(
     '    dept' => 884
      ),
     '11:03' => array(
         'dept' => 297
      ),
  ),
 '91' => array (
    '11:00' => array(
       'dept' => 297
     ),
  )
);
```

As you can see the dept id 297 returned only once.

I tried the code below:

```
function filterSuccessiveDuplicates($array)
{
  $result = array();
   $lastValue = null;
   foreach ($array as $arr =>$value){
      $value = array_values($value);
        foreach($value as $k => $v){

          if ($v['dept'] !== $lastValue) {
            $result[$arr][$k] = $v;
          }
          $lastValue = $v['dept'];
      }
   }
   return $result;
}
 print_r(filterSuccessiveDuplicates($array));
```

But its not working. The output is not what I want. Any help?

Comment: useruseruser that is not correct answer, because 297 is repeated . check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to keep your $lastValue inside first loop.. And remove that `array_values()`

```
function filterSuccessiveDuplicates($array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $arr =>$value){
        $lastValue = null;
        foreach($value as $k => $v){

            if ($v['dept'] !== $lastValue) {
                $result[$arr][$k] = $v;
            }

            $lastValue = $v['dept'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r(filterSuccessiveDuplicates($array));
```

I tested it.. It works well.

Here is the output.

```
Array
(
    [90] => Array
        (
            [11:01] => Array
                (
                    [dept] => 297
                )

            [11:02] => Array
                (
                    [    dept] => 884
                )

            [11:03] => Array
                (
                    [dept] => 297
                )

        )

    [91] => Array
        (
            [11:00] => Array
                (
                    [dept] => 297
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I have a  question why did you remove the array_values?

Comment: @useruseruser that is not correct answer, because 297 is repeated . check once.

Comment: @Anant, 297 should not be repeated consecutively. Read the question properly.

Comment: look at his expected output. @Anant